Ehcahe 3 CacheEventListener not trigger automatically after the ttl(Time To Live) time got over
I have a CacheEventListener of ehcache3 and I have set ttl time 30 sec after 30 the listener is not calling automatically
Below is my ehcache.xml file
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd"\>

    <cache alias="cacheFiles">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>java.util.List</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">30</ttl>
        </expiry>
    
        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>com.cacheabstraction.listener.CacheEventLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
    
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config\>

and this is my listener class
public class CacheEventLogger implements CacheEventListener<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(CacheEvent<? extends Object, ? extends Object> event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.EXPIRED && event.getOldValue() != null) {
            System.out.println("TTL expired for key: " + event.getKey());
            // Add your logic to handle TTL expiration event here
        }
    }

Tried multiple way but still the Cache Even Listener is not running automatically

You did not mention the application nature where you are using ehcache. I'm using Spring Boot 3 with the JSR 107 related dependencies and configuration integrated. The interesting thing is events get fired for Spring @Cacheable annotation marked methods but not for 2nd level caches hits. If you still interested provide more details.
